# How to send json string body for FakeRequest without using withJsonBody in Play framework v2.x?

Tags: json, scala, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have play scala v2.3 application. I'm trying to create a controller test by sending json string with FakeRequest as below:

```
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {

    "Create Bob Test" in new WithApplication {
      val jsonStr = """{"text": "hi bob"}"""

      val result = route(FakeRequest(POST, "/bob")
        .withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
        .withBody(jsonStr)
      ).get

      status(result) === OK
    }
  }
}
```

The controller:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def bob = Action.async { request =>
    println("request.headers: " + request.headers)
    println("request.body: " + request.body)
    println("request.body.asJson: " + request.body.asJson)

    request.body.asJson.map { json =>
      // do something with the json
      Future.successful(Ok)
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest))
  }

}
```

When I run the test, it's failed and this is what printed:

```
request.headers: ArrayBuffer((Content-Type,List(text/plain; charset=utf-8)))
request.body: AnyContentAsText({"text": "hi bob"})
request.body.asJson: None
```

So the `Content-Type` header sent is not `application/json` despite I have set the header with `application/json`. And probably because of that, the `request.body.asJson` returns None.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Note: I know I can use `.withJsonBody(Json.parse(jsonStr))` on the FakeRequest and it will succeed, but with this way I can't send broken or invalid json string for negative test case since `withJsonBody` accepts JsValue which the json string must be converted first with `Json.parse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `Content-Type` header gets overridden by the framework. A workaround is given in the [blog](http://chepurnoy.org/blog/2013/02/play-framework-v-2-dot-1-how-to-test-actions-processing-binary-streams/)

In your case, this should work

```
route(FakeRequest(POST, "/bob", FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE->Seq("application/json"))), jsonStr))(Writeable(_.getBytes, None)).get
```

For multiple tests, an implicit can be created in the beginning for the `writable` and it need not to be passed in every test:

```
implicit val wString: Writeable[String] = Writeable(_.getBytes, None)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It can be shortened into `Writeable(_.getBytes, None)` thus: `route(FakeRequest(POST, "/bob").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").withBody(jsonStr))(Writeable(_.getBytes, None)).get`, or if I have many tests, I can just create an implicit val for that: `implicit val wString: Writeable[String] = Writeable(_.getBytes, None)`.

Comment: do you know why would it not hit the `/x-endpoint/y-endpoint` from tests? - Here are my controller and routes/ https://gist.github.com/prayagupd/7307203#gistcomment-1903507